# Why is Python sending me mixed messages about an object's type?

Tags: python, psql

I am using `psqlparse` to parse tables out of psql statements. This library isn't really complete. For select statements, it returns a `psqlparse.nodes.parsenodes.Statement` object, where I can just call `parsenode.tables()` to get the tables. For some other statements, it returns a dictionary that the library actually parses to create a `Statement` object.

I can't get the tables used for one query because I can't even tell what type of object `psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0]` is returning.

```py
print("psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query) = {!r}".format(psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)))
print("psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0] = {!r}".format(psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0]))
print("type(psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0]) = {!r}".format(type(psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0])))
```

outputs

```
psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query) = [<psqlparse.nodes.parsenodes.SelectStmt object at 0x7f9a8f80a5f8>]
psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0] = <psqlparse.nodes.parsenodes.SelectStmt object at 0x7f9a8f751320>
type(psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0]) = <class 'psqlparse.nodes.parsenodes.SelectStmt'>
```

---

```py
print("psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0].keys() = {}".format(psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0].keys()))
```

outputs

```
AttributeError: 'SelectStmt' object has no attribute 'keys'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-127687> in <module>
----> 1 print("psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0].keys() = {}".format(psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0].keys()))

AttributeError: 'SelectStmt' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

---

```py
"psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0].tables() = {}".format(psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0].tables())
```

outputs

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-127688> in <module>
----> 1 "psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0].tables() = {}".format(psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)[0].tables())

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psqlparse/nodes/parsenodes.py in tables(self)
     47         if self.from_clause:
     48             for item in self.from_clause:
---> 49                 _tables |= item.tables()
     50         if self.where_clause:
     51             _tables |= self.where_clause.tables()

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psqlparse/nodes/parsenodes.py in tables(self)
    185 
    186     def tables(self):
--> 187         return self.subquery.tables()
    188 
    189 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psqlparse/nodes/parsenodes.py in tables(self)
     44         if self.target_list:
     45             for item in self.target_list:
---> 46                 _tables |= item.tables()
     47         if self.from_clause:
     48             for item in self.from_clause:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psqlparse/nodes/parsenodes.py in tables(self)
    217                 _tables |= item.tables()
    218         elif isinstance(self.val, Node):
--> 219             _tables |= self.val.tables()
    220 
    221         return _tables

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psqlparse/nodes/parsenodes.py in tables(self)
    250         if self.args:
    251             for item in self.args:
--> 252                 _tables |= item.tables()
    253         return _tables
    254 

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tables'
```

Comment: Stop catching the exception. Let it propagate, so you see the stack trace. You're obscuring most of the information by catching the exception and doing `print(e)`.

Comment: Why did you write the same thing over and over? Use variables instead! E.g. `parsed = psqlparse.parse(tagged_no_table_query)`, `obj = parsed[0]`, then you can do e.g. `print("parsed = {!r}".format(parsed))`. Also use the spec `{!r}` to print an object's representation, which is better for debugging.

Comment: Now that you have the full stack trace, you can see that the exception is actually coming from **inside** the `tables` method, in a recursive call, and there is no ambiguity about the original object's type.

Comment: ok, thank you @user2357112supportsMonica!